# JBPM Standalone designer

Tags: java, jbpm, kie

I have deployed jbpm standalone designer.
I want to connect it with repository of already installed jbpm(installed with jbpm full installer).
How can I configure standalone designer to access projects from business central repo and store newly created project back to the same location.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: What sort of details should I provide?

Comment: There are different jbpm designer available which one you are using?

Comment: I have jbpm standalone web designer which was deployed using jbpm-designer-standalone-wildfly8.1.war file.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Eclipse JBPM designer you could refer this article.

[Configure JBPM process Designer](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html)

check section 18.3.1. Importing a workbench repository

Comment: Thanks for the above information. How can we do similar stuff with jbpm standalone web designer?